Why $\log_2f_1(n)$ is not $O(\log_2 f_2(n))$ if $f_1(n) = O(f_2(n))$?
I'm studying asymptotic notation and I found a question on the chapter 02 of the book Algorithm Design [Kleinberg_Tardos] - version 03 of the book:
There is a question about which is big-O of which between:

$f_1(n) = 2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}}$ and $f_2(n) = 2^n$

On the answer of the book it says I can apply log in both sizes like this:

$\log(f_1(n)) = \log(2^{\sqrt{\log_2n}})$ and $\log(f_2(n)) = \log(2^n)$,

So I can see $f_1\le f_2$ since  :

$\log(f_1(n)) = \sqrt{\log_2n}$ and $\log(f_2(n)) = n$
and $\sqrt{\log_2n} \le n$.

Therefore, since $f_1(n)$ is $O(f_2(n))$, for me this proves that $\log_2(f_1(n))$ is $O(\log_2(f_2(n)))$ .

But if I get $\log_2(f_1(n)) = O(\log_2(f_2(n)))$
and choose $f_1(n)= 2$ and $f_2(n)= 1$
and apply the statement it does not work, since applying the logarithms I will have:

$\log_2(2) \le c*\log_2(1)$ which gives $1 \le 0$


I am getting lost somewhere here, but not sure where

I am sorry but it is a pet peave of mine when people come on here for help and are sloppy about formatting their mathjax. If you want people to help w your question at least make it easy for them to read!

Sorry, I learned yesterday about this mathjax thingy, I thought it was good on the original post (I can assure I was not sloppy and I lost a lot of time trying to make it work).

In my (now deleted) answer, I was misled by your sentence "Therefore, since $f_1(n)$ is $O(f_2(n))$, for me this proves that $\log_2(f_1(n))$ is $O(\log_2(f_2(n)))$". You already proved that $\log_2(f_1(n))\le\log_2(f_2(n)))$, and this allowed you to claim that  $f_1(n)=O(f_2(n))$. I don't understand why you are reasoning backwards in that sentence.

Hi Anne, I proved for a specific case  of $(f_1(n))$ and $(f_2(n))$ that $\log_2(f_1(n))$ is $O(\log_2(f_2(n)))$ and then I wanted to prove for a general case. Doing this, I realised the statement is not True because I found a conter-example when $(f_1(n) = 2)$ and $(f_2(n) = 1)$. So I could not understand how I could do the "log application" for the specific case if the general case was not working. Hence the question

My point in the previous comment was that you did not "do the log application for the specific case". You reasoned the other way round: you compared the logs of the functions, and derived a comparision of the functions themselves.

You've successfully discovered that the implicit theorems you're using have required hypotheses! A true theorem is:

If $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and both $f(x)\ge1$ and $g(x)\ge2$ everywhere, then $\log f(x) = O(\log g(x))$.

This can be strengthened to:

Let $\delta>0$ be fixed. If $f(x) = O(g(x))$ and both $f(x)\ge\delta$ and $g(x)\ge1+\delta$ everywhere, then $\log f(x) = O(\log g(x))$.

The best way to understand why these assumptions are needed ... is to write proofs of the theorems!
(And by the way, it is not true that $\log f(x) = O(\log g(x))$ implies $f(x) = O(g(x))$, as the example $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x$ demonstrates. If you're familiar with little-$o$ notation, it is true that $\log f(x) = o(\log g(x))$ implies $f(x) = o(g(x))$, which is very useful.)

Oh! Thank you! But how can you find this hypothesis on ()≥1 and ()≥2 ? I mean, I gave a conter-example but from a conter example it be a hypothesis?  For example, I can see that $2^f = O(2^g)$  also is fake since it do not work for the example f = 2n and g=n. But how can I find the hypothesis for this case?Is it ()≥1n and ()≥2n?

You can either look in books or other sources that state these theorems rigorously, or you can propose a rigorous theorem statement and see if you can prove it yourself.
